# multiple nginx config files under nginx/conf.d/ and 404

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

A seemingly very simple reverse proxy config is giving me headache here.
Main config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf has 
`"include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;"`

Then I have two conf files under conf.d:
`default-1.conf` and `default-2.conf`
First file has:

```
server {
  # HealthCheck 
  server_name _;
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl ;
  location = /health.html {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 }
}
```

And second file has additional proxy statements as

```
server {

 listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl ;

 server_name www.example2.com;    
 ...    
 location / {    
 set $backend "some-backend";    
 proxy_pass $scheme://$backend;     
 }  
}
```

When there is only default-1.conf is under conf.d/, 
`curl -k https://localhost/health.html` works.

If I also put default-2.conf under conf.d/, then same curl command gives 404 Not Found. I don't see any error under error.log either.
What am I doing wrong?

How can I learn the rules applied during building final conf file using these multiple smaller conf files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `server_name _;` doesn't make this a default catch-all server. From NGINX [Server names](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> In catch-all server examples the strange name `_` can be seen:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen       80  default_server;
>     server_name  _;
>     return       444;
> }
> ```
>
> There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad
>   of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name.
>   Other invalid names like `--` and `!@#` may equally be used.

And a bit further:

> Note that there is no way to specify the catch-all name or the default
>   server using the [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive. This is a property of the
>   [`listen`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive and not of the [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive.

Your `default-1.conf` should have:

```
server {
    # HealthCheck 
    listen       0.0.0.0:443  ssl  default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location = /health.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for clearing server_name and listen directives for me.